# I am sorry, I am <name> and I am happy usages

Tags: grammar, phrases

When someone asks our name, we use *I am [name]*. Also, we use *I am* to express our feelings, like *I am sorry*, and *I am happy*. So do we use *I am* for both our identity and our feelings?

Comment: 'I am' is **never** called a _prefix_; that term is already taken and universally agreed upon in linguistics. The copula _be_ is very commonly used to show identities ('I am John') and states ('She is cold') (_be_ is used in other ways; it's very versatile). // Though 'He is a disciple _and_ a leader' and 'I'm tired and hungry' are totally acceptable, a mixed statement ('I'm a leader and angry') is not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Unlike some other languages (eg Spanish, Japanese), English uses the same copula *be* for contingent properties, innate properties, identity, and sometimes location:

> I am happy (contingent or transitory property)
>
> I am human (innate or permanent property)
>
> I am Colin (identity)
>
> I am in my house (location).

Comment: great. the words late, right and wrong does they belong to contingent or transitory properties?. Like, i am late, i am right, i am wrong....etc...

Comment: Given that I've just pointed out that English doesn't distinguish these kind of properties, I wonder why there is any point in asking this question here. But I would say that none of them is innate or permanent (though some people act as though being "right" is a permanent attribute that they have!)